# Is there any way to show GUI without loop? Or another way to fix it?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When keylistener `on_press` is above `root.mainloop()` autoclicker works, but the GUI doesn't show.

I tried to move keylistener under `root.mainloop()` and GUI works perfectly, but it doesn't click.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
import time
import threading

from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

delay = 0.001
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='f')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()

def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()

#keylistener
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

root = Tk()

#gui code
#I don't wanna show it :P
root.geometry("300x350")
root.title("autoclicker")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

I want autoclicker with GUI made in python

> Errors: root.mainloop()

blocks keylistener and it doesn't click, program doesn't show any errors.

Comment: They block each other. Look into multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

The Listener blocks because it waits until you stop it and the join can complete, hence any code after it is never executed.
Similarly, `root.mainloop()` will block the main execution and tell Tkinter to handle any events on your GUI. The mainloop will only exit after calling `root.destroy()` (e.g. when pressing the X-button to close a window).

You should create your GUI and then call the Listener code when you press a Button or a key when the GUI is focused e.g. use:

```
root.bind("<KeyPress-F>", func=a_function_to_call_when_F_was_pressed)
```

Comment: I don't want to close window when press x, I forgot to delete this from code :P But I don't understand your answer can you change my code and send me fixed? ;/

Comment: What do you want to do with Tkinter then if you don't want to show a GUI?

Comment: I wanna show GUI, but ```main.loop ()``` blocks key listener and I want to fix it